# python 3: Write to File from Cursor Based List

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is homework, and I am pretty new to Python. I have written a text editor program that uses a doubly-lined cursor based list class. I have had the user either open an existing file to edit, or a new file, and created a cursor-based list for that file. At the end, I want the user to be able to save whatever changes they've made back to the file. I am getting some errors and not sure what to do. Any advice is appreciated!

```
from cursor_based_list import CursorBasedList
from os.path import exists
import os

def main():
    def seeFile():
        """Asks the user if they want to view their file after editing, and
            if yes, prints the file without None, front, or rear."""
        seeFile = input("Would you like to see your file now? Y/N: ").upper()
        while not seeFile == "Y" and not seeFile == "N":
            print("That is not a valid choice!")
            seeFile = input("Would you like to see your file now? Y/N: ").upper()
        if seeFile == "Y":
            print()
            print(fileList)

    print()
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("Welcome to TextEd v.1, a friendly text editor program!")
    print()
    print("How would you like to begin?")
    print()
    print("O: Open an existing text file for editing")
    print("N: Create a new text file for editing")
    print()
    response = input("Please choose an initial option: ").upper()
    while response != "O" and response != "N":
        print("That is not a valid initial option.")
        response = input("Please choose an initial option: ").upper()
    if response == "O":
        fileName = input("Enter the file name: ")
        while not exists(fileName):
            print()
            print("File " + fileName + " does not exist!")
            fileName = input("Please enter a valid file name: ")
        myFile = open(fileName, 'r')
        data = myFile.readlines()
        fileList = CursorBasedList()
        for line in data:
            fileList.insertAfter(line)
        seeFile()
    elif response == "N":
        fileName = input("What would you like to name your file?: ")
        fileList = CursorBasedList()
        myFile = open(fileName, "w")

    print()    
    print("TextEd Menu:")
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print()
    print("A: Insert a new line after the current line of your file")
    print("B: Insert a new line before the current line of your file")
    print("C: Display the current line of your file")
    print("F: Display the first line of your file")
    print("L: Display the last line of your file")
    print("E: Display the next line of your file")
    print("P: Display the previous line of your file")
    print("D: Delete the current line of your file")
    print("R: Replace the current line of your file with a new line")
    print("S: Save your edited text file")
    print("Q: Quit")
    while True:
        response = input("Please choose an option: ").upper()
        if response == "A":
            line = input("Enter the new line to insert after the current line: ")
            line = line + "\n" 
            fileList.insertAfter(line)
            seeFile()
        elif response == "B":
            line = input("Enter the new line to insert before the current line: ")
            line = line + "\n"
            fileList.insertBefore(line)
            seeFile()
        elif response == "C":
            line = fileList.getCurrent()
            print("The current line is:", line)
        elif response == "F":
            first = fileList.first()
            print("The first line is:", fileList.getCurrent())
        elif response == "L":
            last = fileList.last()
            print("The last line is:", fileList.getCurrent())
        elif response == "E":
            try:
                nextLine = fileList.next()
                print("The next line is:", fileList.getCurrent())
            except AttributeError:
                print("You have reached the end of the file.")
        elif response == "P":
            try:
                prevLine = fileList.previous()
                print("The previous line is:", fileList.getCurrent())
            except AttributeError:
                print("You have reached the beginning of the file.")
        elif response == "D":
            fileList.remove()
            seeFile()
        elif response == "R":
            item = input("Enter the line you would like put into the file: ")
            item = item + "\n"
            fileList.replace(item)
            seeFile()
        elif response == "S":
            temp = fileList.first()
            while temp!= None:
                result = str(temp.getData())
                myFile.write(result)
                temp = temp.getNext()
            myFile.close()
            print("Your file has been saved.")
            print()
        elif response == "Q":
            print("Thank you for using TextEd!")
            break
        else:
            print("That is not a valid option.")

main()
```

Everything is working wonderfully, except for saving. Something else to point out is that when I get to myFile.close(), I get an error saying that "the list object has no attribute close."

If you'd like to see more code please tell me! I know this is probably not "perfect" code, so bear with me. Thanks!

```
elif response == "S":
            myFile = open(fileName,"w")
            fileList.first()
            current = fileList.getCurrent()
            try:
                for x in range(len(fileList)):
                    myFile.write(str(current))
                    current = fileList.next()
                    current = fileList.getCurrent()
                    print(current)
            except AttributeError:
                myFile.close()
                print("Your file has been saved.")
                print()
```

Okay, I finally got it to work with the above code. I'm sure this is probably about the ugliest way to write it, but at least it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you assign `myFile` here:

```
        myFile = open(fileName, 'r')
```

At that time, myFile is a file object. However, then you do this:

```
        myFile = myFile.readlines()
```

Now myFile is a list containing all the lines in the file, and as such cannot be closed anymore. Assign `myFile.readlines()` to a different variable and you'll be fine.

See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) about file input/output.

`fileList` is also empty at the time of writing, because when you open the file to write you also set `fileList` to a new `CursorBasedList` here:

```
elif response == "N":
        fileName = input("What would you like to name your file?: ")
        fileList = CursorBasedList() # <- Here
        myFile = open(fileName, "w")
```

If you remove that line, it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I made that change and it's reflected in my code above. I no longer get an error, but when I save, nothing is actually saved to the file. I still have the original file, or if I created a new file, there is a blank file. Any guesses? :)

Comment: I tried adding a new command to open the file for writing, but that didn't seem to help. When I did it on the existing file, it erased the contents like I expected but then did not write the new list to the file.

Comment: Amended my previous answer, see above.

Comment: Thank you. I get what you're saying, but I need that at the beginning of my program to initialize an empty list so that I can add to it. Without the initialization,  the methods for adding lines will not work. So I am not sure what to do. I appreciate the assistance!

Comment: You assign it twice, once in the `O` clause and once in the `N` clause. The one in the `N` clause is superfluous, you can remove that. If you want to initialize it so you don't get an `NameError` later, do it at the start of `main()` instead of in the `N` clause.

Comment: Oh, of course. Thank you! It's still not saving anything to the file, but it's an improvement.

Comment: The issue is not with the writing. I can't say if the problem is with the `CursorBasedList` as I don't know the implementation. Can you check if anything is in the list or if it's empty? Try printing out the lines as you write them, if the log is empty, nothing was in the list. If that still doesn't work, can you give me an example of which keys you press in which order, so I can try to trace through what the program does?

Comment: I have figured out how to get temp (or current) not to equal None, it just won't write to the file now. It says it is unwriteable.

Comment: Where does it throw the Error? Can you post it along with a stack trace? Are you sure the file has been opened correctly, have permission to write, etc.?

Comment: I finally got it to work. It was unwritable because I was just calling the Node, not calling the data in the node. Once I changed that it now works. I couldn't have gotten this to work without your tips. Thank you so much for sticking with me!